# javascript promises inside then

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I've recently discovered the promises, and they made my life much easier.
But there is a specific case that I'm not being capable to handle. It is when I have to call a promise inside then().

Here is my code:

```
const firebaseAuth = require("firebase/auth");
const auth = firebaseAuth.getAuth();
const { User } = require('../models/User');

app.post('/create_user', (req, res) => {
     user_uid = req.body.params.uid;
     newUserEmail = req.body.params.email;
     newUserPassword = req.body.params.password;
     let user;
     firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUserEmail, newUserPassword)
     .then((userCredential) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         if(userCredential == undefined) throw Error("createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed");
         user = new User(userCredential.user.uid, req.body.params.userAttributes);
         resolve()
     }))
     .then(firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null))
     .then(/*other functions using User object*/)
     .then(() => {                  // finished promise chaining
        res.status(200).send();
     })
     .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(403).send();
    })
});
```

The problem is, the `.then(firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null))` is being called before the user is initialized in `user = new User(userCredential.user.uid, req.body.params.userAttributes);`.
Could someone please help me understand why is this happening? And in case I have to call a promise inside a then(), Do I also have to nest a .catch()? Or my single .catch() at the end of my function will be capable to handle possible errors?

Edit: User does some async tasks inside the constructor, because it has to handle the images.
And I can only Initialize it, after `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUserEmail, newUserPassword)` because I have to get the generated Id in `userCredential`

Comment: Use `.then(() => firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null))`. The argument of `.then` is _evaluated_ immediately, it must evaluate to a function, which is then _executed_ after the promise is resolved.

Comment: How will the user the initialized?  It does some async tasks inside the object, because it has to handle images. @HeikoTheißen And I can only Initialize it, after `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUserEmail, newUserPassword)` because I have to get the generated Id in `userCredential`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. The most simple fix for your code is to change this line:

```js
     .then(firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null))
```

to

```js
     .then(() => firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null))
```

notice the the the arrow function wrapping the call to `firebaseAuth`, before your code was the equivalent of asking `firebaseAuth` to return a function that would handle that step of the promise chain.

2. If the only purpose of `return new Promise()` is to do the validation and get the user, you can simply.

```
  .then((userCredential) => {
   if(userCredential == undefined) throw Error("createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed");
    return new User(userCredential.user.uid, req.body.params.userAttributes);
  })
```

and the user will be available in the next chain as

```
.then(user => {
  // do stuff with user
})
```

Comment: Actually needs to be a promise to handle the user, because It receives an Image in base64 at `req.body.params` and It is an async task to decode it. And, btw, doing: `.then(user => {
  // do stuff with user
})`, will I have to return the user in every then() chain?

Comment: returning the user in every chain I made it work like you said with, `.then(user => {
  // do stuff with user
})`. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` function and `try` block to `await` the **userCredential** value like this:

```js
app.post('/create_user', async(req, res) => {
  user_uid = req.body.params.uid;
  newUserEmail = req.body.params.email;
  newUserPassword = req.body.params.password;
  let user;

  try {
    const userCredential =
      await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        newUserEmail,
        newUserPassword
      );

    if (userCredential == undefined)
      return res
        .status(400)
        .send('❌ CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword failed ');

    user = new User(
      userCredential.user.uid,
      req.body.params.userAttributes
    );

    await firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null);

    return res.status(201).send('Created!! ');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('❌ Error:', error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: error,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the efford, I really appreciate, but, as I described in `.then(/*other functions using User object*/)` I have to do other async operations, using the await functions would be a possibility but the code becomes too big and verbosal :/ I'll upvote for the efford xD

Answer (score 1):

We should never find `new Promise()` wrapping a library that already creates promises.

Also remember that the form of a chain is....

```
// promiseA, promiseB & promiseC are expressions that evaluate to promises
return promiseA.then(resolutionOfPromiseA => {
  // synchronous work
  return promiseB;
}).then(resolutionOfPromiseB => {
  // synchronous work
  return promiseC;
}).catch(error => {})
```

In newer syntax:

```
async function myFunction() {
  try {
    let resolutionOfPromiseA = await promiseA;
    // synchronous work
    let resolutionOfPromiseB = await promiseB;
    // synchronous work
    return promiseC;
  } catch(error) {
  }
```

Sticking with the OP's older syntactic style (which is perfectly good as long as it remains consistent)

```
 let user;
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUserEmail, newUserPassword)
 .then(userCredential => {
     // note that we don't create a promise
     if(userCredential == undefined) throw Error("createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed");
     user = new User(userCredential.user.uid, req.body.params.userAttributes);
     // note that we return this one. It's good form, even if the next then doesn't use the result
     return firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null)
  })
 .then(res => {   // this res is the result of firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail
   // user is in scope here because it's in the containing scope
   /* other functions using User object */
 })
 .then(() => {                  // finished promise chaining
    res.status(200).send();
 })
 .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(403).send();
})
```

**edit** If you really wanted `user` in the block after `sendPasswordReset`, and you really didn't want to keep a user variable in the containing scope, you could say...

```
  // move let declaration here
  let user = new User(//...

  // string an extra return user here
  // some linters think this is a faux pas
  return firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.attr.email, null)
    .then(() => return user)
)}.then(user =>
```

Comment: As user does some async tasks in the constructor, I'll return the user in the `.then(userCredential...)` but, still, best answer.

Comment: @CesarLopes, you *can* return it (by nesting a then, some frown upon this), but note that you located the `let user` in the containing scope (wrapping both then functions) so user is available anyway to all of them.  What you did is a slightly less structured, but perfectly acceptable way to share scope between thens.  I described in more detail in an edit